# It didn't show any error, but the compiler just keep loading or show [object object]

Tags: java, debugging, loading

I was tring to make a leagth converter which can convert foot to other units which are micrometer, millimeter......
when I try to run it, it just keep loading and sometimes will show [Object Object]....(I dont know wheather [Object Object] is an error

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Converter{


public static void calculateMicro(double number){
double answer =   304796.293632 * number;
System.out.print ("The answer is: " + answer );
}
public static void calculateMilli(double number){
double answer =   304.8 * number;
System.out.print ("The answer is: " + answer );
}
public static void calculateCenti(double number){
double answer =   30.48 * number;
System.out.print ("The answer is: " + answer );
}
public static void calculateMeter(double number){
double answer =   0.3048 * number;
System.out.print ("The answer is: " + answer );
}
public static void calculateKilo(double number){
double answer =   0.0003048 * number;
System.out.print ("The answer is: " + answer );
}
public static void main (String args[]) {
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

double number = sc.nextDouble();
int x = 1;
int option = sc.nextInt();

while(x==1){
   System.out.println("1.micrometer  2.millimeter  3.centimeter  4.meter  5. kilometer");
  if(option==1){
    calculateMicro(number);
  }
  else if(option==2){
    calculateMilli(number);
  }
  else if(option==3){
    calculateCenti(number);
  }
  else if(option==4){
    calculateMeter(number);
  }
  else if(option==5){
    calculateKilo(number);
  }
}
```

Comment: This is Java, not JavaScript.

Comment: What is the purpose of the loop? You're not asking any user input in that loop and `x` is never changing, so it will just keep looping forever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are made an infinit loop by

```
int x = 1;
while(x==1){
//code...
}
```

You should

1. Ask the user for the option
2. Ask the user if he want try another time (change the x to 0 or 1 )

```
while(x==1){
   System.out.println("1.micrometer  2.millimeter  3.centimeter  4.meter  5. kilometer");
x = sc.nextInt();
  //code to convert....
 System.out.println("do you wanna try again 1 for Yes or 0 for No");
x = sc.nextInt();
}
```

and i think if you have multiple choice you should try Switch not if else if else ....

```
switch(option) {
  case 1:
        calculateMicro(number);
    break;
  case 2:
        calculateMilli(number);
    break;
  //cases
//  default:
}
```

Comment: Sir Even though I dont use any loop. it just keeping running

Comment: but you use while, and it is a loop!
while(x==1){
//convert
}